# Extension speed issues (database read/write) after upgrade to TYPO3 v10.4

Tags: typo3, extbase, typo3-10.x

After upgrading our TYPO3 website from 8.7 to 9.x to 10.4, a custom-made extension has become twice as slow. More specifically, the reading and writing of the database queries have become slower.

The extension uses (long and complex) TYPO3 Extbase repository queries and are full compliance with TYPO3 code conventions.

How come the exact same, unaltered queries run twice as long in TYPO3 v10 compared to v8.7? It is important to mention that no changes were needed to the repository/query code (other than the TCA code and other configuration files) to successfully run the extension in TYPO3 v10. The only issue is the reduced database reading/writing speed.

Also, the v10 TYPO3 instance runs on the exact same server and the same environment. The only difference is the PHP version (7.1 vs 7.3).

Any insights into this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Not really sure why but my guess is how the relations between tables are handle by TYPO3. The only "issue" that i personally have with TYPO3, is how expensive in time  is the object construction while reading/updating/creating. The Lazy attribute helps but not always

Answer (score 0):

One thing that comes to my mind is SQL indices, which TYPO3 v9 creates automatically for typical fields (pid,deleted) of a DB table, but maybe you had some additional indices before? can you recheck this?

In addition, if it is related to languages and overlays this might be an issue as well. Is this only in Frontend environments or also observed in TYPO3 Backend?